# How to regex compare a string in dash?

Tags: regex, bash, dash-shell

I'm moving a bash script to dash for compatibility reasons. Is there a POSIX/Dash alternative to the following comparison?

```
COMPARE_TO="^(lp:~?|https?://|svn://|svn\+ssh://|bzr://|bzr\+ssh://|git://|ssh://)"

if [[ $COMPARE =~ $COMPARE_TO ]]; then
    echo "WE ARE COMPARED!"
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a case. It doesn't use regex, but it's not that much longer with globs

```
case $compare in
    lp:*|http://*|https://*|svn://*|svn+ssh://*|bzr://*|bzr+ssh://*|git:/*|ssh://*)
        echo "We are compared"
    ;;
esac
```

On a side note, you should [avoid using all uppercase variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/1524545) as you risk overwriting special shell variables or environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

dash doesn't have regex comparing built in, but you can always use grep:

```
if echo "$compare" | egrep -q "$compare_to"; then
    ...
```

(Note that I second @geirha's note about uppercase variables in the shell.)

Comment: `echo` is always a bit scary in this sort of context. The `case` answer is more idiomatic and elegant, and solves the problem entirely without external processes.

Comment: @tripleee: I consider the `case` statement's syntax highly inelegant, but I agree it's more idiomatic and saves subprocesses (provided you can express your pattern as a glob rather than a regex, and you can in this particular case). BTW, if you're worried about echo, use `printf "%s\n" "$compare"` instead.